# Expanded Distribution Coverage: Mathematica 11

Tags: distributions

When Mathematica 11 released a few months ago there was the following image under Wolfram's promotional material [Expanded Distribution Coverage](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/extended-probability-and-statistics/expanded-distribution-coverage.html?product=mathematica):

[image: enter image description]

However, the image is quite small and some of the text is too pixelated to read and I cannot find a version large enough to read *or* a list of comparisons to other languages.

Does anyone know this information? The only other thing provided on the site is the caption:

"Version 11 adds new scalar and matrix distributions, widening its already significant lead over the competition."

Comment: isn't funny that going to the page you linked [extended-probability-and-statistics/expanded-distribution-coverage](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/extended-probability-and-statistics/expanded-distribution-coverage.html?product=mathematica) and then clicking on the `Expanded Distribution coverage>>` link below, send you back to the same page started at? A circular loop of links. I agree with you, the image should be readable. Given that it is so prominently displayed at center of page and it is the whole point of the web page! But can't read what is inside it.  WRI should really fix this :)

Comment: @Nasser that is exactly what I was thinking. It just seemed really odd and out of place. Why make this image available and then obscure it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have asked this question and [@Searke](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/144/searke) provided the following image (quite large when you click on it to follow its link) in the [Mma.SE chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/31627452/history).

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this. It wasn't anything pertinent, but I was curious. Also, I looked at your post and you use `[@username]` to make a link to a user. However, I can not do the same. Does that require a specific level of points to do?

Comment: @SumNeuron notice the parentheses after the brackets. `[text](URL)` is the syntax.

Comment: @edmund, it rendered on another line and I did not see it! my bad

Answer (score 3):

You could always run

```
Names["System`*Distribution"]
```

There's some extraneous symbols in this list, but it seems fairly exhaustive.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't give you the comparison. :)